# Compiling ES6 to ES5 constructor in loose mode

Tags: javascript

In the *Exploring ES6* book, I was reading about how constructors are compiled to ES5 in loose mode. One example is this:

```
class Point {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    toString() {
        return `(${this.x}, ${this.y})`;
    }
}
```

Is compiled into this:

```
"use strict";

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
  if(!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
    throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
  }
}

var Point = (function () {
    function Point(x, y) {
        _classCallCheck(this, Point);

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    Point.prototype.toString = function toString() { // (A)
        return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
    };

    return Point;
})();
```

I don't understand this line:

```
_classCallCheck(this, Point);
```

So what does `Point` actually mean here? Does it refer to the `function Point`? In which case, of course `this` is an instance of `Point`because it also refers to `function Point`, so `_classCallCheck` will always return `true`.

Comment: I think it's to ensure `Point` is instantiated using the constructor syntax.  That way, a consumer of the class  will get a typeerror if they accidentally call `let x = Point(1,2)` instead of `let x = new Point (1,2)`.

Answer (score 2):

> So what does Point actually mean here? Does it refer to the function Point?

Yes

---

What `_classCallCheck` is doing is checking to see if a new instance of the class Point was created. It prevents someone from doing the following:

```
var test = Point(); // THROWS ERROR
```

In the previous snippet example, `_classCallCheck(this, Point)`, `this` will be whatever the outer scope of this code is (probably window).

---

It forces you to instantiate a new instance:

```
var test = new Point(); // VALID
```

Answer (score 1):

> So what does Point actually mean here?

It is the `Point` function, which is stored in `var Point`.

> In which case, of course this is an instance of Pointbecause it also refers to function Point, so _classCallCheck will always return true.

Not so. It's easy to call `Point` in such a way that `this` is not an instance of `Point`. ES6 classes, by their nature, prevent calling class names in this way, but ES5 does not, so the `_classCallCheck` is there to ensure ES6 behavior is preserved. Observe:

```js
"use strict";

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
  if(!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
    throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
  }
}

var Point = (function () {
    function Point(x, y) {
        _classCallCheck(this, Point);

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    Point.prototype.toString = function toString() { // (A)
        return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
    };

    return Point;
})();

// Invalid call prevented by _classCallCheck
Point(1, 2);
```